# How to pass a file as an argument in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having some issues passing an argument in a python script to take a specific file like a csv, txt, or xml
I am reviewing python and would like some feedback on why I don't see any output after running the following command:  ./my_script some3455.csv

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

FILE = str(sys.argv[1])

def run_files():
    if FILE == '*.csv'
       run_csv()
    elif FILE == '*.txt'
       run_txt()
    else
       run_xml()

def run_csv():
    csv_file = csv.register_dialect('dialect', delimiter = '|')
    with open(FILE, 'r') as file:
      reader = csv.reader(file, dialect='dialect')
      for row in reader:
        print(row)

def run_txt():
    with open(FILE, 'r') as file:
      txt_contents = file.read()
      print(txt_contents)

def run_xml():
    tree = ET.parse(FILE)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root.findall('Attributes')
      car = child.find('Car').text
      color = child.find('Color').text
    print(car, color)
```

I have tried to pass it as without the FILE but works just for one and the other file types doesn't get identify.

Comment: So, what's your question exactly?

Comment: The TODOs part, how to write or append a manifest to a file in a directory or subdirectory based on that csv information, then output a comparison of those files with created manifest in those directory or subdirectory if there are duplicates, modify files, for ex.

Comment: I would recommend you try to write a solution and if you run into actual problems doing so, to ask focused questions about those problems. The code you've shared here only sets up the situation, but doesn't provide any part of the solution you actually need - StackOverflow isn't the right place to ask people for recommendations on libraries or to write software for you.

Comment: I have giving great feedback in the past specially if i am refreshing a language again, not to write a software for me. You misunderstood my intentions.

Comment: Apologies, but you answered my previous question fairly clearly, indicating that you're asking people how you should go about writing software to do a certain job. That sounds very much like asking people what software they recommend or to write something for you. How am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Grismar I changed my question.  So not the same anymore.  I couldn't ask any other question due to your input, if anyone can help great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fnmatch` and not `==` to compare a string with a glob pattern:

```
import fnmatch

def run_files():
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(FILE, '*.csv'):
       run_csv()
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(FILE, '*.txt'):
       run_txt()
    else:
       run_xml()
```

Comment: In addition to this fix of the problem, I would pass `FILE` as a parameter to the `run_` functions, and make an alternative for `FILE` a local variable of the `run_files` function.

Comment: @Grismar I would agree if this script were ever to be used as a module.